# Ignore push notification when app transit from background to foreground

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

I want to ignore any push notification when app comes from background to foreground and at the same time any push gets received.I am doing this because I am not able to determine if user clicked on push notification or app received push at the transition time.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add these lines in applicationWillResignActive method of appdelegate:

UIApplication.shared.cancelAllLocalNotifications()

and then create notification again.

Comment: method name says local notification, I want to ignore Remote Push notfication.

Comment: ok. please try with this :    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0

Comment: I don't want to change the Icon number. I want that didReceiveNotification should not gets called during the transition.